# Ubuntu 22.04 firewalld initiation problem: no python-nftables

Tags: iptables, firewalld, ufw, nftables

I tried to use `firewalld` instead of `ufw`, but it keeps showing the following errors even after manually downloading `python-nftables` through `sudo apt install`

`iptables` is not being used.

```shellsession
$ systemctl status iptables
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

`FirewallBackend` was already set to `nftables` when I checked on `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`.

- Error Message 1

  ```
  ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
  ```

  JSON blob:

  ```
  {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PREROUTING", "type": "filter", "hook": "prerouting", "prio": -140}}}, {"add": >
  ```
- Error Message 2

  ```
  ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
  ```

  JSON blob:

  ```
  {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "mangle_PREROUTING", "type": "filter", "hook": "prerouting", "prio": -140}}}, {"add": >
  ```

This works but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do this. Modifying `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` to `IPv6_rpfilter=no` works.

Any idea?